# Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. (1/1) NotFoundHttpException in laravel 5.4.28

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

php file inside app\Http\routes.php this is my route code

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function (){

    //getDashboard
    Route::get('dashboard', [
        'as'    => 'get.register',
        'uses'  => 'dashboardController@getCreate'
    ]);


});
```

and when i go to my url 
http://localhost/crudlara/public/dashboard
it displays the error of

Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
(1/1) NotFoundHttpException

Can someone help me figured this thing out?
in laravel version 5.2.10 that route code im using runs well.

Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Shouldn't it be `DashboardController@getCreate`?

Comment: what you mean? didnt get you

Comment: `dashboardController` vs `DashboardController`

Comment: i just changed it to DashboardController still error hmmmm

Comment: try  http://localhost/dashboard

Comment: its wrong if localhost/dashboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using 5.4, you should put all routes into the `routes/web.php` file and remove `'middleware' => ['web']` part.

Comment: no, just `routes/web.php` . You have the `routes` folder in your project root since 5.4

Comment: Hi thanks for your help it worked now. can i ask some question for this one? (2/2) ErrorException

View [main] not found. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\crudlara\resources\views\dashboard.blade.php)

Comment: @PHPDev looks like the `dashboard` view extends or includes `main` view which doesn't exist. If you'll not be able to fix that, please create another question and put `dashboard` view contents in it.

Comment: thanks. i already solve it i just create a min.blade.php file